# What is the default configuration for logrotate.conf in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

In `/etc/logrotate.conf` is user permission different from one ubuntu version to another?  .... and why ??
as i found it like that in ubuntu 18.04

```
# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog
```

and like that in ubuntu 20.04

```
# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group 
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root adm
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are actually asking here, Can you [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1083543/edit) the question to they and break it up into multiple sentences and be a little bit more verbose.

Comment: Which versions do you get this from? I can see one version in 18.04 and the other in 20.04, but the 20.04 version states the default group is adm in the comment.

Comment: In 20.04 I see `# use the adm group by default, since this is the owning group`, which is not the same as in your question.

Comment: i've edited it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaults you posted are correct for the versions already stated.

The change was introduced with [Eoan](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+source/logrotate/+changelog) based on [bug report 1644996](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/logrotate/+bug/1644996), which stated the default group changed in `16.04`, but the bug only affected lighter versions of Ubuntu that do not come with `rsyslog` already installed.